# jQuery Hide/Remove error message when re-validate correct input

Tags: jquery, validation, message

How could I hide/remove error message assigned to each field after users have rectified their input again? the script below will display error message when input are invalid, but when user key-in valid values again and click button, the error message is still there, how to fix it?

This is callback

```
 $('#btn_register').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#register_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success == 'success'){

                alert('Success');
                $('#register_form')[0].reset();

            }else{
                if(response.error.email != ''){
                    $('#email_error').html(response.error.email);
                }
                if(response.error.password != ''){
                    $('#password_error').html(response.error.password);
                }
                if(response.error.rpassword != ''){
                    $('#rpassword_error').html(response.error.rpassword);
                }
                if(response.error.fname != ''){
                    $('#fname_error').html(response.error.fname);
                }
                if(response.error.contact != ''){
                    $('#contact_error').html(response.error.contact);
                }
                if(response.error.dob != ''){
                    $('#dob_error').html(response.error.dob);
                }
                if(response.error.captcha != ''){
                    $('#captcha_error').html(response.error.captcha);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });

});
```

this is form field to display error message when callback is invalid:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br /><span class="error" id="email_error"></span>
```

Please advise and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the given mark up I'll be doing something like

```
success: function(response){
    if(response.success == 'success'){
        .....
    } else {
        $('[id$="_error"]').html('');

        $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
            if(value){
                $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To clear all the error messages, the logic is based on the assumption that all the error placeholder elements has the `id` attribute ending with `_error`, then use the [attribute ending with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('[id$="_error"]').html('');
```

But I would recommend adding a class like `error-label` to all the error place holders and change `$('[id$="_error"]').html('')` to `$('.error-label').html('')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" onChange="resetInput(this);"/>

function resetInput(placeholder) {
      $('#'+$('placeholder').attr('id')+'_error').text('');
}
```

or try in your ajax success :

```
    success :function () {
    $('[id$="_error"])').text('');
if(response.success == 'success'){
                alert('Success');
                $('#register_form')[0].reset();
            }else{...............}
    }
```